# webpage not showing up on android apk

Tags: android, css, cordova, mobile

I'm using phonegap to basically let me make a web page that seems like an app, and the page fine in the native browser on android, works fine in the emulator, but when it comes to the app (which is the same resolution as the emulator) there is simply a white blank page..

Any ideas?

I've installed the apk before and uninstalled it.. might it have something to do with this?

Comment: Run "adb logcat" to see what the errors are.

Comment: have you included cordova-[version].js in your index.html?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your Activity does not have the:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Perhaps, your layout is empty and that line still exists together with the:

```
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/dummy.html");
```

You can also include a *config.xml* file in your /res/xml folder (/res/xml/config.xml)

Here is a sample of a basic one:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cordova>
<access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/> <!-- allow local pages -->

<log level="DEBUG"/>
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
<preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false" />
  <plugins>
     <plugin name="App" value="org.apache.cordova.App"/>
     <plugin name="InAppBrowser" value="org.apache.cordova.InAppBrowser"/>     
  </plugins>
</cordova>
```

I've had similar trouble when I first started experimenting with phonegap. 
Also, make sure that the *cordova-2.2.*.jar is in your libs folder and it is also referenced in your build path.

Hope that helps.